What's the pragmatic way to use an audio worklet in Angular?
I understand we can always load an audio worklet the native way (by using AudioContext.audioWorklet.addModule), but it requires us to write it in pure Javascript and handle dependency bundling ourselves. Is there a more natural to write an audio worklet in angular? - i.e. preferrably we could write it in Typescript and let angular bundle the dependencies for us.
I saw Angular has web worker support but they does not seem to be quite the same thing.

I've come to a workaround for this problem.

Write the worklet as if it's a web worker. This is perfecly supported by Angular. Now the problem is, to load the compiled worker script, we don't have a trivial way to get its URL.

Wrap the worker code like this:


if (typeof self !== "undefined") {
  postMessage(self.location.href);
} else {
  // do the worklet thing
}

When self is not undefined, we know this script is loaded as a webworker (in a worklet context it would be undefined). In this case, send the script's location by postMessage.

When trying to load the worklet, first load it as a web worker, wait for it to report the location, then terminate the worker and use the location to load the worklet.

E.g. load an audio worklet:
// probe worker url
const worker = new Worker(
  new URL("path/to/the/worker", import.meta.url),
);

const url = await new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
  worker.onmessage = (e) => {
    resolve(e.data);
    worker.terminate();
  };

  worker.onmessageerror = reject;
});

await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule(url);

I've also filed a feature request on the angular repo for built-in support of worklets.
